# getting error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have written a piece of code, to get some information through the website and display it in a `ListView`. I am not able to configure why i am getting the force close error. I am pasting the log cat along with the code. Please help me find and solve the error

```
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.air.test/com.air.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:47)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:169)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:138)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at com.air.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-07 21:43:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     ... 11 more
```

**Code**

```
private Spinner spinner1;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private StringBuilder response;
private ListView listView;
private String[] values;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int id,
                long ids) {
            new sendMessageAsync().execute();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> av) {
        }
    });

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class sendMessageAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading...",
                true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Message Sending Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            doInBg();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}

public void doInBg() {
    try {
        final String msgURL = "http://example.com/message?category="
                + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()
                        .replace(" ", "%20"));
        URLConnection connection = new URL(msgURL).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                responseStream));
        response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        values = String.valueOf(response).split("<br/>");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: this `String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()
                        .replace(" ", "%20"));` causing problem because ui elements is not accessible in  doInBackground

Comment: @imrankhan thats not the problem at all. because the code was running perfectly when i assigned static value to `values`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your String array `values` before attempting to create the adapter.

This line will fail because `values` is `null`:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Comment: I am doing that using `AsyncTask` to assign value to `values`

Comment: Then you will need to set an initial value (i.e. an empty array) and then make sure you're properly synchronizing the variable if you're setting it from the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: Change the declaration to: `private String[] values = new String[0];`

Answer (score 4):

When this line is run, `values` is null.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

To solve this, initialize `values` before that line.

```
values = new String[0];
```

Or, if you want it to contain something:

```
values = new String[]{ "Value 1", "Value 2" };
```

**EDIT:**

Having checked your AsyncTask implementation, here's what I would do:

I would first of all initialize the value using this code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, new ArrayList<String>());
```

Secondly, I would get rid of your `values` String array as a class property. (Delete the line `private String[] values;`)

Thirdly, I would change the AsyncTask to `<Void, String, Void>`.

Fourthly, assuming that this code would give you the correct result:

`values = String.valueOf(response).split("<br/>");`

Here I would replace that line with:

```
String[] values = String.valueOf(response).split("<br/>");
for (String str : values) publishProgress(str);
```

And then, in your AsyncTask, have this method:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    adapter.add(values[0]);
}
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: I want the values to be added dynamically from the website. Therefore i have used this code `values = String.valueOf(response).split("<br/>");`

Comment: @TapanDesai I have edited my answer to something I think should work with your AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry if i am wrong but did you forget to complete this step in your answer? `Thirdly, I would change the AsyncTask to .`

Comment: @TapanDesai Sorry about that, it was interpreted as an HTML tag I guess, it should say `<Void, String, Void>`.